# Store class variable in dictionary

Tags: python, class, dictionary, tkinter

I am making a program that will have a box that receives two inputs, an event name and the time allocated for the event, and will later output a list of all the events that have been added. This is the class for the input boxes:

```
class agendaEvent:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.name = Entry(self.frame)
        self.name.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.time = Entry(self.frame, width=10)
        self.time.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
```

I am fairly new to programming, but I believe the correct way to store the `name` and `time` would be in a dictionary.

There could be multiple instances of the class running at the same time and more could run after these have already been stored. It would be preferable to have them all stored in the same dictionary.

However, I do not know how to store the `self` variables in a dictionary that I could later access outside of the class. Is this possible? If so, how? If not, how could I store the variables in a way that they could be accessed in a separate function?

EDIT: This is the minimal code (I think) needed to replicate my issue:

```
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial


class agendaEvent:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.name = Entry(self.frame)
        self.name.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.time = Entry(self.frame, width=10)
        self.time.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
        self.label1 = Label(self.frame, text="Event Name")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label2 = Label(self.frame, text="Minutes")
        self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1)

def addOne(master):
    this_instance = agendaEvent(master)

def addEvent():
    window = Toplevel()
    addOneButton = Button(window, text='+1', command=partial(addOne, window))
    addOneButton.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)
    doneButton = Button(window, text='Done', command=partial(done, window))
    doneButton.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=3)

def done(windowInstance):

    #This is where I was thinking
    #the code for storing information
    #should be because it should store
    #when the done button is pressed.
    #This may not be a good way to do it,
    #I don't know. 

    windowInstance.destroy()
    windowInstance = ""



root = Tk()


addEventButton = Button(root, text="Add Events", command=addEvent)
addEventButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe name and time. what is currently preventing me is my lack of knowledge. I do not know how make a dictionary that would store name and time from all the instances of agendaEvent, which I could then access in a separate function later in the script. First off, would dictionary be the right way to go about this? And if so, how exactly would one do this?

Comment: Maybe https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=python+dictionary+example would be the place to start?  ;-)

Comment: @boardrider I have tried to search for but I cannot find the answer. Most of my problems I can solve with Google, but for the ones I can't find by searching, I come here. When I can't find it here, I make my own post in hopes someone knows how to help me.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my end goal is to have a main window with a master list and the class agendaEvent open up in a side window. A user would then select the number of events they wish to add, and for each one they would type the name and time. They would then click a done button, and in the main window, a master list would show all the events they have added. The side window would also close when the done button is pressed. I have just about everything, except for the ability to transfer the information inputted in the side window to the main window's master list. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If so, I would love to hear. Again, I am new to coding and I am open to hearing anything that could help me improve my abilities and fix my problem as efficiently as possible.

Comment: If a `self` is a process/thread, then it has a `$PID` or equivalent that uniquely identify it. You could store that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I hardly think I need the whole program rewritten. The class represents one input line in the secondary window. Each input line has an event space and a time space. When I click the done button, I want the information from all of the input lines to be put into the master list in the main window. Maybe a dictionary is not the correct solution for this information storage and transfer. The agendaEvent class will be ended, so I thought it made sense. If it is not the solution you would use, I trust your opinion and would love to hear what I should look into as a better solution.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if I edit the post to contain the full script, would it help you help me? I am very lost and I need help to complete my program. Based on your account information, you seem to know what you are doing and I feel as though there must be a solution to my problem, and if there is, you would know. Please tell me what it is I need to do that will give you the information that you need to help me.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited the post with the script needed to replicate my issue. There is no error, I just cannot find a way to access and store the information for all the instances of the agendaEvent in one "area" (at this point I don't know what the best method for storing would be, list, dict, etc) and be able to access them all later to display in the main window.

Comment: I phrased that wrong, I don't want to store ALL the information, just the name and time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe do you have any ideas as to what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what you need to do is store the `agendaEvent` instances you create in a list; then you can iterate over the list afterwards:

```
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial

events = []  # place to store the instances

class agendaEvent:

    ...


def addOne(master):
    events.append(agendaEvent(master))  # store the new instance in the list

def addEvent():
    ...

def done(windowInstance):
    for event in events:
        ...  # use event.time, event.date, etc.
    windowInstance.destroy()
    windowInstance = ""

root = Tk()

addEventButton = Button(root, text="Add Events", command=addEvent)
addEventButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You may also need to clear the list in `done`, if this section can be called again.

Comment: This works almost perfectly. The one issue I am having is that I used the variable this_instance for a few commands later in the function addOne, to add a remove button to its frame, and to use as an argument in the remove function. I cannot figure out how to call the specific item in the list to achieve the same function. Is there a way to do this? I appreciate your help, I'm sorry if my questions are stupid. I just don't really understand coding very well, hence the reason I am trying to learn.

Comment: @JohnHall then leave `events.append(this_instance)` until *after* whatever other setup you need, or use `events[-1]` to access the last item you placed into the list.

Comment: `for event in events:
        lbl = Label(root, text=event.name)
        lbl2 = Label(root, text=event.time)`

Comment: @JohnHall oh good, unreadable code in a comment. Is that a question?

Comment: didnt mean to send that alone, that is what my code looks like, but when i display the labels, it just displays a long string of numbers and the 2 are identical. I am not quite sure what I have done wrong, but I assume there is some sort of function I have to apply to get the actual numbers I input, was going to check standard library first, but now I accidentally sent that.

Comment: @JohnHall please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Your error is so vague as to be impossible to help you with. But shouldn't you be using the *content* of the `Entry`, rather than the object itself?

Comment: yes, that is what I intend to do. I was about to ask you a question and I prepared the code (of course it turned out horrible), then decided it would be better to check the library myself first and see if I could fix it without bothering you. I accidentally pressed enter and the comment was sent. If you could tell me how to use the content of the Entry, I would appreciate it, but otherwise I can probably just find it in the documentation. Thank you for all of your help though.

Comment: as expected, I was able to figure it out, it was quite simple. Once again, thanks for all your help. Just starting out coding, it makes me more confident to know that if I need help there will (hopefully) be people like you I can turn to in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class variable for storing data available outside the instance. Assuming you want to store names mapped to times you could add the following (this assumes that the Entry class is hashable):

```
class agendaEvent:
    instances = dict()  # Class variable, access with agendaEvent.instances

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.name = Entry(self.frame)
        self.name.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.time = Entry(self.frame, width=10)
        self.time.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
        self.instances[self.name] = self.time
```

Now to access these values from elsewhere use:

```
 agendaEvent.instances
```

E.g. if you have a name Entry stored in 'name' retrieve its time Entry with:

```
time = agendaEvent.instances[name]
```

Comment: Is an `Entry` a valid dictionary key?

Comment: Yep it seems to be. Just tried it out to make sure it is.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to store agenda events in a dictionary, you will have to serialize the agenda events object before storing it as the value and de-serialize the object when trying to access its name or time.

You could do this using a library such as [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or do it yourself using Json strings.

From your question, I'm not sure if this is what you want to do.

Comment: I don't want to store the actual class instance. I want to store the variables obtained through the entries within the class, self.name and self.time. My issue comes with storing self variables in a dictionary accessible anywhere and also with making all of the instances store in the same dictionary. I have very little knowledge of how to use dictionary, and I am trying to learn, but I cannot find the answer to my issue.

Comment: Using  Redis, a key-value cache and store, will give you a dictionary that is accessible anywhere.  Storing the instances as a value in the Redis cache will give you access to the `self.name` and `self.time` variables of that instance.

Comment: would the information still be retained after the instances have been ended? Also, could it cause performance issues if upwards of a hundred instances of events were stored in this manner?

Comment: Yes the information will be retained. That is the point of using Redis - a key value cache and _store_ . As for performance, I'm still not sure of what your are trying to do and can't give you an exact answer. However if you read up on Redis you will see that everything is held in memory. Therefore if you are storing large amounts of data there could be performance issues.